# Stopping clicks on object on one stage going through to the nextStage in EaselJS / CreateJS

Tags: events, createjs, easeljs, stage

I have two canvases and two stages in CreateJS / EaselJS. The first stage has autoClear set to false and I am doing dynamic drawing on it starting with a stagemousedown event.  The second stage uses nextStage to send mouse events to the first stage.  The second stage has interface such as a Bitmap that I want to press on to go to another page.  When I click on the Bitmap, the stage beneath does the dynamic drawing.  I want the click on the Bitmap not to go through to the first stage but stopImmediatePropagation does not work, nor does putting a clone of the Bitmap with mouseEnabled false on it underneath.  I can just use mousedown on the Bitmap so the user does not notice as much, but was wondering if there is a way to disable mouse events from passing through the top stage if they are acting on an object with an event set to capture? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you calling `stopImmediatePropagation`? This shouldn't help because something on the first stage would have to receive the MouseEvent, preventing `nextStage` from getting it.  Is your first stage Bitmap receiving the mouse event as well?

Comment: oh, are you hoping that stopping propagation on stagemousedown will prevent click mouse events on other content?

Comment: Thanks Lanny, I am trying to prevent a click on the top stage from propagating to a stagemousedown on the bottom stage (or even a click on the bottom stage for some other case in the future).  I have nextStage set on the top stage to point to the bottom stage.  I assume that the top stage is the second stage made (or the second canvas made with no z-index adjustments).

Answer (score 0):

The `stagemousedown` and other stage events are decoupled from the EaselJS object event model. They are catch-all events, which basically represent mouse interaction with the . Because of this, catching and stopping these events won't interrupt the display list hierarchy.

Typically if you want to block other events in the same stage, you can create a canvas-size box (Shape, etc) that will block the interaction. When dealing with `nextStage`, this is especially true, since we are passing on events that are unhandled by objects in the EaselJS display list.

A better approach might be to toggle the `nextStage` on `stagemousedown`, so it is null during the click event. Not sure if this will work, but its a start.